# Cakephp ARO lft and rft generation

Tags: cakephp

Working on a SSO plugin and having issues for the SSO users. I have added them to a role that local users use but its not working. The issue I believe is that I do not have anything in the aros table, the lft and rght, for the SSO user. I believe this is why its not working but not sure. Could someone help me understand how I can generate those or just what they are used for? Most documentation is really limited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `lft`, `rght` values are for [MPTT](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). If you don't have proper values for those fields CakePHP won't be able to properly traverse the records of table (using [TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html)).

Remove the records you added by hand and instead use [ACL Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/acl-shell.html) to add the records.

In general [TreeBehavior::recover()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior%3a%3arecover) can be used to fix the `lft`, `rght` values.

Comment: So you are saying that in my controller where I am adding the user, I can call $this->Aros->recovery(); I tried this and getting blackholed